# Split array values to object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I was wondering how to convert an array to an object by splitting the values ?

```
var obj = {
    id: '',
    val: ''
}
```

By this I mean - if I have an array like

`["abc12", "abc1", "def12", "abc454"]`

How I could `split` the first 3 values off - so it end up like an object like:

```
{id: 'abc', val: 12}, {id: 'abc', val: 1} ...
```

Comment: Are you asking for an array of objects as the output? `[{id: 'abc', val: 12}, {id: 'abc', val: 1} ...]` - and do you want to split exactly on three characters, or perhaps split based on letters versus digits?

Comment: yeah letters vs digits would be much better if can show me ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to map your array (like herby noted) with a function that converts an element of your array to an object of your desired form.
In this case, the `id` is represented by all the characters before the first digit and the `val` represents the digits from the back of the string :

```
source.map(function(x) {
    return { 
        id: x.replace(/(^.*?)\d+$/,'$1'), 
        val: parseInt(x.replace(/^.*?(\d+)$/,'$1'),10) 
    };
});
```

**[Here's a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NTYqP/1/)**

Ps: You may want to be careful and check if the `map` method exists in the `Array` prototype chain, because older browsers may not have this implemented. Here's a link that explains how to cover this browser incompatibility : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_map.htm.

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT: Not an answer to the question

*This will not result in the desired mapped array, but in a single object. 
Sorry, misread your question :(*

The answer below will return one single Object and not an array of Objects.

---

You can easily fold such arrays into objects with the array's `reduce` method:

```
var source = ["abc12", "abc1", "def12", "abc454"];
var obj = source.reduce(function(o, str) {
  var key = str.substr(0, 3)
  var value = parseInt(str.substr(3))
  o[key] = value;
  return o;
}, {})

// obj = { abc: 454, def: 12 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
source.map(function(x) {
  return { id: x.substr(0,3), val: +(x.substr(3)) };
}
```